# Creando una plantilla maestra django

Tags: django

Hola mi duda es la siguiente , estoy siguiendo este tutorial https://www.uno-de-piera.com/crud-con-django-y-mysql/comment-page-1/#comment-12083 y lega el punto donde que vaya al directorio templates y cree un archivo html pero no se o no hay un directorio de tal tipo, revise el settings.py  y no se si ahi es donde se le agrega un directorio (supongo que por versiones anteriores a django no me lo hizo como en el tutorial o se saltaron esa parte)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

es ahi donde le debo indicar un directorio para que lea los templates y si fuera ese caso: ¿Ese directorio lo creo dentro de alguna app o en la carpeta del proyecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario que crees una carpeta llamada `templates` dentro de tu aplicación. Dentro de esa carpeta podrás crear todos tus templates, los cuales son llamados desde los métodos de la vista (archivo `views.py`).

La explicación un poco más larga es que esto está implícitamente 
configurado en un objeto dentro del arreglo `TEMPLATES` en el archivo `settings.py`. La propiedad `BACKEND` de ese objeto define el motor de templates que se va a utilizar, (en este caso `django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates`) y la propiedad booleana `APP_DIRS` le indica al motor si es que debe o no buscar archivos de templates dentro de las aplicaciones instaladas. Cada backend tiene definido un nombre para el subdirectorio dentro de las aplicaciones en el cual va a buscar, y en el caso del backend `DjangoTemplates`, el nombre es `templates`. Por eso se debe crear esa carpeta dentro de la app y poner ahí los archivos html de templates. Más detalles en este [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/templates/#configuration)

Comment: y debo modificar algo mas? nada mas cree una sola aplicacion django dentro de esa es donde creare mi carpeta templates cierto? y cuando mas o menos le dire que ahi estan los template necesarios? en la urls.py ?

Comment: El motor de templates lo encuentra por convención del nombre `templates`.  Por lo tanto cuando en una vista haces referencia a `'form_posts.html'`, entonces lo que se buscará es un archivo en la ruta `templates/form_posts.html`.
 Agregué una explicación más detallada a mi respuesta.

Comment: eres el mejor :D amo esta comunidad